# Timestamp#equals() fails if Timestamp is mapped to/from Database

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, jdbc, timestamp

I am using `DATETIME` in my MS SQL Database to store date and time.

Java to Database: `preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, insertObj.getTimestamp());`

Database to Java: `selectedObj.setTimestamp(result.getTimestamp("datetime"));`

Comparing them in my unit tests with `insertObj.timestamp.equals(selectedObj.timestamp);` randomly returns true or false.

Is this a known issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: So your database column is of this type: [`DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), and your Java variable is of this type: [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)? And what JDBC driver?

Comment: @Basil Bourque yes this is how you insert DATETIME values into the Database, there is no 'setDatetime()' or anything else in JDBC, the JDBC Driver will correctly handle the conversion from Timestamp to DATETIME, it is working some time, and some time the returned timestamp differs exactly 1ms from the inserted

Comment: (A) You did not actually answer my questions. (B) I am familiar with how JDBC works. (C) Add example data values to your Question.

Comment: All your answers can be found in my question: Microsoft SQL Server, DATETIME column, java.sql.Timestamp, Microsoft JDBC 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL Server [`DATETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) has +/- 3 millisecond accuracy:

> Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

In other words if you insert a value with a sub second fraction of `.001`, it will be stored as `.000`, `.002` as `.003`, etc, making the equals check fail for such values. You can also have this effect if you have sub-millisecond precision in the `Timestamp` (eg storing a `Timestamp` with a sub-second value of `.0001` will be rounded to `.000`), see also below.

If you want a more precise storage, then you need to use [`DATETIME2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which has 100 nanosecond accuracy, otherwise you need to account for the rounding, for example by checking if the absolute difference between the two values is less than 3 milliseconds, eg:

```
Math.abs(insertTimestamp.getTime() - selectedTimestamp.getTime()) < 3
```

Just be aware that `java.sql.Timestamp` can contain up to nanosecond accuracy (so if you'd store values with a resolution higher than 100ns in `DATETIME2`, you can still have this problem). You normally have millisecond accuracy, but you can get nanosecond accuracy if explicitly set using [`setNanos`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#setNanos-int-) (which is used to set sub-second nanosecond values) or if created from one of the `java.time` classes. See also the [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) API doc:

> **Note:** This type is a composite of a `java.util.Date` and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the `java.util.Date` component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you! One more question: has the TIME data type in SQL similar behaviour? I do not really need such precision, I only need to get the exact same value back I stored.

Comment: @Pali, see the [documentation for `time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx): _"Accuracy 100 nanoseconds (1 millisecond in Informatica)"_, however `java.sql.Time` only has second precision, but you should be able to set/get a `Timestamp` to a `time` field, but you'll lose the date information.